# Can't load local jpg files in my angularjs project

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I have started a small angularjs app project using yeoman's generator-angular.

When adding jpg files to the app/images folder, and try to use an  tag linking to one of these jpg files, they don't show up in the browser.

When using png files everything it ok (Using same absolute path /images/image.png and /images/image.jpg). If I use a remote URL to a jpg file everything works fine.

What am I missing here? I have the same problem using the  tag. When using a local absolute path, it doesn't work and when I use a remote url everything is fine.

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: can you link some code about how your using the images? Check out [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

Comment: @agconti <img src="/images/img-1.png" alt=""/> works but not <img ng-src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt=""/> ... yes the two files are there.

Comment: Have you tried taking a remote `.jpg` that works, and copying it into your local environment, and then try to access it locally? Point being, ruling out that your local `.jpg` files are corrupted in some way?

Comment: The jpg works ok outside of AngularJS (in a browser)

Comment: I am having this same problem. I can reference the yeoman.png image but not another in the same folder.

Comment: @Sean what was problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using html5Mode? If so and if you are using connect-modrewrite to rewrite urls to index.html, make sure you have excluded jpg and jpeg files.  I recently encountered the same issue and didn't realize my rewrite rule was excluding png images but not jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an angular expression `{{}}` for [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) to work.

For example, using this html markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <img ng-src="{{ path }}" />
</div>
```

with a controller like:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.path = 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/';
};
```

will allow angular to load, do its magic, and then correctly reference the image source from the `path` variable held in `$scope` from the controller.

Else, the image trys to load from the `src` attribute hasn't had time to get a value yet.

Demo in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6jMDp96we0S7DGyGTtxw?p=preview

Comment: Same problem, remote url ok not local path to jpg (png is ok)